# Prism 4.1 инициализация

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism

Установил призму 4.1 (ФВ 4.0)

Читаю мануалчики. Во всех сказано, что для начала нужно создать наследника от класса `Bootstrapper`. И один из переопределенных методов должен выглядеть как то так

```
protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
{
    return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Shell>();
}
```

Но что это за `Shell`? Я не могу найти такой тип.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Shell` - это принятое в Prism название класса главного окна. Дефолтный WPF проект создаёт этот класс под названием `MainWindow`, если мне не изменяет память. То есть смысл в том, что вы и не найдёте этот класс, его нужно создать самому.